# store printed id label and use it to insert as an array number php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

In the code below, I am trying to get the generated Div ID label and insert it dynamically into the array number in the #inline div at the bottom. possible?

```
<?php if ($top_fundraisers && is_array($top_fundraisers)): ?>
        <?php foreach ($top_fundraisers as $index => $fundraiser): ?>

           <a href="#inline1" class="fancybox">
            <div id="name<?php print htmlentities($index + 1); ?>">
              <?php print htmlentities($fundraisers['member_name']); ?> *STORE THIS ID*
            </div>
           </a>

        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<div id="inline1" display: none;">
      <?php print htmlentities($top_fundraisers['name+number(generated above)'] ['member_name']); ?>*GENERATE STORED ID* HERE
</div>
```

Comment: move the bottom 3 lines to the foreach loop and set the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep an IDs array - use the IDs as key and store the member names while in the foreach loop.

```
ids[$index+1]=$fundraisers['member_name']
```

Then use foreach with this array.